# varargs with single and multi-dimentional arrays

Tags: java, generics, lambda, variadic-functions, consumer

I have the following code in java working fine for var args and single dimensional arrays.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    MyConsumer<Integer> method1 = n -> n * n;
    Integer[] result1 = method1.run(10);
    for(Integer i : result1) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    
    MyConsumer<Integer> method3 = n -> n * n;
    Integer[] result3 = new Integer[]{10, 100};
    method3.run(result3);
    for(Integer i : result3) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
interface MyConsumer<T> {
    T execute(T args);
    default T[] run(T ...args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            iterate(args);
            return args;
        }
        return null;
    }
    default void iterate(T ...obj) {
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            if (obj[i].getClass().isArray()) {
                iterate(obj[i]);
            } else {
                 obj[i] = execute(obj[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want this to work for multidimensional arrays as well, like for the following:

```
MyConsumer<Integer> method5 = n -> n * n;
Integer[][] result5 = new Integer[][]{{10, 100}, {20}};
method5.run(result5);
for(Integer[] i : result5) {
    for (Integer j : i) {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

The above fails to compile with the following error

```
error: method run in interface MyConsumer cannot be applied to given types;
```

The code in the interface will work for var args and all dimensional arrays, but the problem here is to accept a multi dimensional array as varargs parameter we have to define the parameter type and return type with that no.of dimensions like for -

- 2 dimensional parameter type is `T[]... args` and return type is `T[][]`
- 3 dimensional parameter type is `T[][]... args` and return type is `T[][][]`

Can someone please suggest me the solution or other alternatives!!
Solutions I thought are method overloading.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most specific common supertype of `T[]`, `T[][]`, `T[][][]`, etc. is `Object[]`. So your method can take an `Object[]` (or equivalently, `Object...`) parameter, but that means you lose type safety -- the compiler will not check that the passed argument is type `T[]`, `T[][]`, `T[][][]`, etc.

(Thankfully, we don't need to deal with arrays of primitive types. If we had to deal with arrays of primitive types, the only common supertype we can use is `Object`, and we would have to use the methods of `java.lang.reflect.Array` to interact with it generically. However, since we are only dealing with arrays of reference types, we can use the supertype of `Object[]`, and can use regular array operations on the `Object[]`.)

So your `iterate()` method can be something like this:

```
default void iterate(Object... obj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (obj[i] instanceof Object[]) {
            iterate((Object[]) obj[i]);
        } else {
             obj[i] = execute((T) obj[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing to mention is that this will only work when `T` isn't itself a subtype of `Object[]`. This method doesn't know what `T` is, and will simply recurse down to the first level that isn't an instance of `Object[]`, and assumes that that is `T`. But if `T` is itself an array-of-reference-type type, then this will recurse down too deeply into the component type of `T`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by `@newacct`, is correct. And it comes at a cost of manual type casting for following cases:

```
MyConsumer<Integer> m = n -> n * n;
Object[] res = m.run(10);
for(Object i : res) {
    System.out.println((Integer)i));
}
```

or

```
MyConsumer<Integer> m = n -> n * n;
Integer[][] a = new Integer[][]{{10, 100}, {20}};
Integer[][] b = new Integer[][]{{10}, {20}};
Object[] c = m.run(a, b);
for(Object res : c) {
    for (Object[] i : (Object[][])res) {
        for (Object j : i) {
            System.out.println((Integer)j);
        }
    }
}
```